# How do I use INSTR in MASM?

Tags: assembly, masm

I've been wrapped around the axle all day trying to figure out why INSTR isn't finding a carriage return in my text file.  How do I get the INSTR macro to read the text and find the line breaks?

```
    .data
     CRLF db 13,10,0

    .data?
    hFile DWORD ?
    bytesRead DWORD ?
    tmpstr BYTE 1825 DUP (?)

    .code

println_arr MACRO arr
    lea EAX, arr
    print EAX
ENDM

start:
    mov hFile, fopen("books.txt")
    mov bytesRead, fsize(hFile)
    mov bytesRead, fread(hFile, addr tmpstr, 1825)

    strpos TEXTEQU @InStr( , tmpstr, CRLF)

    print "Position of first instance of '"
    println_arr CRLF
    print "': "
    print str$(strpos), 13, 10

    fclose hFile

    exit

end start
```

Comment: Are you sure that InStr should be used for runtime search? Another problem could be that the C runtime converts newlines to 13 instead of 13, 10. This is because in C it's convenient that '\n' is a character like any other. So try simply searching for 13. If it dosn't work, you can simply write a loop yourself, it will probably teach you much more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the `TEXTEQU` directive evalutes its argument at assembly time rather than at runtime. You may have to find a different method to search for a string at runtime.

<sup>Also, I'd just like to say that code looks nothing like what I'd *expect* assembly code to look like. Maybe I'm just old.</sup>